# Eclipse trouble when building project with GCC

Tags: eclipse, gcc, build

I'm using Eclipse + gcc compiler for ARM Cortex-M3 processors.
After a successfull project build, if I modify a source file and I start build again, it builds the whole project again instead of the only modified file.
I noted the following:
- I go to another build configuration and I successfull build it;
- then I go back to previous configuration and it builds the modifiede file only;
But the problem persists: if I restart build it will recompile all even though nothing changed.

I hope I was clear.

Any suggestions?

Best regards,

Valter

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I didn't understand your question: what do you mean? I click on "build" hammer button. It seems that it started to happen when I simply changed build configuration name because, before this, it has been working properly for months. It seems that make procedure inside Eclipse doesn't recognize that file was already successfully compiled.

Thanks a lot.

Valter